# Are propositional logic/first-order logic complete?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I don't mean "complete" in the sense of the completeness theorem (semantic provability => syntactic provability). I mean "complete" in the sense of the incompleteness theorem (prove all and only true sentences expressible in its language).

In the second sense of "complete", are propositional logic and/or first-order logic complete?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is any meaningful interpretation of "the second sense of complete" in this context that differs from the first. "Every true statement" could only mean "all statements true in every model." Reading the claim that way, completeness is *exactly* completeness in the first sense.

The reason for the distinction in the incompleteness theorem is that we have some *particular* model in mind (arithmetic), and we want to know if we can prove everything true in that model from our proof system together with our axioms. The completeness theorem says that our proof system is fine for such purposes. The incompleteness theorem says our axioms cannot be. Again, the distinction doesn't make sense if we're just talking about a proof system for some language.

Comment: Is the Wiki article on completeness is incorrect? The page seems to contradict what you're saying and distinguishes between "semantic completeness" and "syntactic completeness" in the way I have above: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)

Comment: @debstack I suppose Wikipedia's sense of syntactic completeness does *apply* to first-order logic as a whole, but it definitely doesn't hold and isn't particularly meaningful. That sense of completeness rests on wanting our system to decide every sentence one way or the other, but we *don't* want that for F.O.L. Consider the first-order language with a binary relation symbol "<". Should the sentence asserting "every element has a unique successor" be provable in F.O.L? What about it's negation? Neither is, nor should be provable: the sentence holds in some structures and fails in others.

Comment: is syntactic completeness the kind of completeness we're interested in when we question whether Peano arithmetic is complete? Or are we interested in semantic completeness but in the specific model of arithmetic, as you suggest? Aren't these different concepts?

Comment: @debstack There are a few related issues at play when discussing arithmetic. I'm not a philosopher, but my understanding is that the original hope was to find axioms that were actually *categorical*: they had exactly one model up to isomorphism, and that model was arithmetic. This turned out to be pretty misguided, so the hope was that the axioms could be *complete* in the sense that they prove exactly the sentences true about arithmetic. (This is a variant on semantic completeness, where we're only considering a single model.) Without axioms already in hand, though, there is no ...

Comment: @debstack ... demonstrable test for "truth", so the hope was that we could find axioms that were both 1) obviously true and 2) syntactically complete. This would yield a test for truth, then: the true sentences are exactly those that follow from those axioms. The incompleteness theorems spoiled even this hope. Anyway, that's my mathematician's understanding. The history and classification of these notions really belongs to philosophers, though, so take what I say with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the adjcetives "syntactical" and "semantic" for the notion of *completenss* are not well chosen. Unfortunately, the role played by Gödel as author both of the *Completeness Theorem* (for first-order logic) and the *Incompleteness Theorem* (for formal arithmetic) does not help ...

The two notions are distinct but strictly linked, and both are forms of completeness of a formal theory with respect to the truth.

The notion of completeness dates back to Hilbert who, in his lecture course on the principles of mathematics he taught in the winter semester 1917/18 (that form the basis of Hilbert and Ackermann's textbook (1928)), states the first formulation of the completeness problem as a precise mathematical question to be answered for a system of axioms :

> We want to call the system of axioms under consideration *complete* if we always obtain an inconsistent system of axioms by adding a formula which is so far not derivable to the system of basic formulas.

This general notion can be applied to a logic calculus, [and is what Wiki calls *semantic*] aimed to capture all the logical truths formulable in a given language or type of language.

For propositional logic, the completeness was proved independently by Bernays (1918) and Post (1921).

To Bernays is also due the first clear definition of *universally valid* [*allgemeingultige*] formula.

See David Hilbert & Wilhelm Ackermann, [Principles of Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=45ZGMjV9vfcC&pg=PA68) (engl transl of the 2nd german ed, 1938), page 14 :

> It is now the first task of logic to find those combinations of sentences which are logically true, i.e. true independently of the truth values of the elementary sentences.

And see page 68 :

> A formula of the predicate calculus is called logically true or, as we also say, universally valid only if, independently of the choice of the domain of individuals, the formula always becomes a true sentence for any substitution of definite sentences, of names of individuals belonging to the domain of individuals, and of predicates defined over the domain of individuals, for the sentential variables, the free individual variables, and the predicate variables respectively. The universally valid formulas of the predicate calculus will also, for convenience, sometimes be called simply valid [page 68].

The completenss of first-order logic was proved by Gödel in [1930](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA583) :

> the question [...] arises whether the initially postulated system of axioms and principles of inference is complete, that is, whether it actually suffices for the derivation of every true logico-mathematical proposition, or whether, perhaps, it is conceivable that there are true propositions (which may even be provable by means of other principles) that cannot be derived in the system under consideration. For the formulas of the propositional calculus the question has been settled affirmatively; that is, it has been shown [footnote: *Bernays 1926*] that every true formula of the propositional calculus does indeed follow from the axioms given in *Principia mathematica*. The same will be done here for a wider realm of formulas, namely, those of the "restricted functional calculus"; that is, we shall prove
>
> THEOREM I. Every valid [footnote: To be more precise, we should say "valid in every domain of individuals", which, according to well-known theorems, means the same as "valid in the denumerable domain of individuals".] formula of the restricted functional calculus is provable.

The same notion can be applied to other cases [and this is what Wiki calls *syntactical* and some authors call *Gödel completeness*], like theories purporting to formalize arithmetic; in this case, completeness means to prove every truth pertaining to some more restricted subject matter: the "intended" domain of discorse of the theory.

There is one important difference between the two: while completeness
with respect to logical truths cannot be expected to satisfy a
general law of excluded middle according to which for every sentence in a given
language, either that sentence or its denial will be true, completeness with respect to e.g. the truth for arithmetic can reasonably be
expected to satisfy such a principle.

And here we have Gödel again, in [1930](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA595) :

> The system $S$ [i.e. the system obtained adding Peano axioms to the logic of *Principia mathematica*]  is not complete [entscheidungsdefinit]; that is, it contains propositions $A$ (and we can in fact exhibit such propositions) for which neither $A$ nor $\overline A$ is provable and, in particular, it contains (even for decidable properties $F$ of natural numbers) undecidable problems of the simple structure $(\exists x)F(x)$, where $x$ ranges over the natural numbers.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response. I take it, then, that you and Mike Haskell are more or less saying the same thing. It makes sense why a complete logical system can't be expected to decide between A and ~A for every formula A, and we wouldn't want it to. But I'm having trouble seeing why we want an arithmetical system to do this. I thought system S was just FOL + PA. Wouldn't there still be formulas that we wouldn't want S to decide between, such as 'Barack Obama is president', which is neither a logical nor arithmetical truth?

Comment: @debstack - but "Barack Obama is president" is not expressible in the formal system of arithmetic...

Comment: I thought system S was just an extension of classical predicate logic to include PA. And we can express 'Barack Obama is president' in predicate logic using P(b). Does system S not have predicates/constants, or is the domain of system S restricted to only arithmetical properties/objects?

Comment: @debstack - the system $S$ is the nowaday standard [formal systen for f-o arithmetic](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA599) (now $\mathsf {PA}$) with the constant $0$ and the *successor* function $f$. We cannot express in it "Barack Obama is president" ... unless we prove that Barak Obama is a number.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see the page you linked, but I take it, then, that the domain of system S is restricted to the arithmetical universe (numbers, sets, etc.)? If so, I was just misunderstanding what system S was.

Comment: @debstack - you can see [here](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/h/hirzel/papers/canon00-goedel.pdf), page 4.